# How to redirect to a page after deleting in django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to redirect to a page after deleting an object I don't know but it's not working. The object gets deleted but it doesn't redirect to any page can someone please help me ? 
If you need more code you can ask me.
Thank you !

Views of deleting product

```
@login_required() 
def delete_product(request, product_id):
    delete = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
    form = NewPro(instance=delete)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewPro(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=delete)
        if form.is_valid():
            delete.delete()

            return redirect('store_details')
        else:
            form = NewPro(instance=delete)
    return render(request, "default/product_delete.html", {'form': form, 'delete': delete})
```

url pattern

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from stores.urls import views

app_name = 'stores'

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:store_id>/store_details/', views.store_details, name='store_details'),

]

 urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:product_id>/product', views.product, name='products_details'),
    path('add_products/', views.pro, name='add_products'),
    path('', views.index_products, name='index_products'),
    path('<int:product_id>/detail_product', views.detail_product, name='detail_product'),
    path('<int:product_id>/edit_product', views.edit_product, name='edit_product'),
    path('<int:product_id>/delete_product', views.delete_product, name='delete_product')
```

]

Comment: Hi, The delete request is it ajax?

Comment: Nope it is not Ajax

Comment: Hmm ok, What is the page showed after delete request?

Comment: Reverse for 'store_details' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['stores\\/(?P<store_id>[0-9]+)\\/store_details\\/$']

Comment: there is no `store_details` in this urlpattern?

Comment: I removed it because it was giving a error

Comment: I removed it because it was giving an error.

Comment: where is it then in the stores urlpattern? cauze we need it to so we can use `redirect(reverse('YOUR_APP_NAME:store_details'))`

Comment: chheck the edit but as i told you it gives an error

Answer (score 2):

The error indicate that django cannot resolve the path of the view `store_details`. You can use the `reverse` method  from `django.urls`.

```
from django.urls import reverse

@login_required() 
def delete_product(request, product_id):
    delete = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
    form = NewPro(instance=delete)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # if this form is not valid we rander it again, so no need for else statement
        form = NewPro(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=delete)
        if form.is_valid():
            delete.delete()
            return redirect(reverse('stores:store_details'))
    # if it's not POST method render an empty form    
    else:
        form = NewPro()
    return render(request, "default/product_delete.html", {'form': form, 'delete': delete})
```

**`urls.py` of product app:**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'product'

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:product_id>/product', views.product, name='products_details'),
    path('add_products/', views.pro, name='add_products'),
    path('', views.index_products, name='index_products'),
    path('<int:product_id>/detail_product', views.detail_product, name='detail_product'),
    path('<int:product_id>/edit_product', views.edit_product, name='edit_product'),
    path('<int:product_id>/delete_product', views.delete_product, name='delete_product')
]
```

**`urls.py` of stores app:**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'stores'

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:store_id>/store_details/', views.store_details, name='store_details'),
]
```

**`app_name` attribute in the included URLconf module help in the reverse resolution of URLs**

I hope this will help.

Comment: Hmm I don't understood the part (substitute the value of YOUR_APP_NAME with the value of app_name in your urls.py file.)

Comment: @SaifKhan, check out the edit. post your `urls.py` for clarity

Comment: I have added the urls of products.

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting the form for the post request, move the `else:` back a tab.

Correct Syntax:

```
@login_required() 
def delete_product(request, product_id):
    delete = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
    form = NewPro(instance=delete)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewPro(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=delete)
        if form.is_valid():
            delete.delete()

            return redirect('store_details')
    else:
        form = NewPro(instance=delete)
    return render(request, "default/product_delete.html", {'form': form, 'delete': delete})
```

Comment: Reverse for 'store_details' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['stores\\/(?P<store_id>[0-9]+)\\/store_details\\/$']

Comment: Thats a URLs reverse error that has nothing to do with what I just said. It seems django cannot find the URL you are trying to reach.

Comment: Yes I don’t have issue with the else part I am having issue with the redirecting.

Comment: You can try and import `from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect`

Comment: Also you can try using the DELETE method instead of a POST method.